# Entire graphical session over ssh on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, session

I sucessully connect on my ubuntu 18.04 (guest), on my host Ubuntu 18.04 (host). And I have used `-X` param on ssh connection to open graphical applications. But now I want to open an entire session over "`ssh -X`"; can you help me with this?

I need to open everything, gnome with nautilus and superior docker and left docker all with my normal graphical session.

Comment: VNC is often suggested for this.

Comment: Check [`xpra`](https://xpra.org/).

Comment: Does any of [these proposals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26172/229880) suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

You could also run gnome over `ssh`. But this will interfere with the system on the local.

Or you can use **VNC over ssh**. `ssvnc` on the local, and a vnc server on the remote. I `ssh` in and launch a vnc server on the remote, setting it to localhost only (then only anyone on the remote (or with ssh connection) can access the vnc server).